# how can i restrict a file being viewed or downloaded using url? i want same file to be downloaded using php script

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to restrict a pdf file on my server from being viewed or downloaded. for example, when somebody types below url in browser and press enter.

http://example.com/pdf/sample-pdf1.pdf

the file should not be viewed or downloaded. instead, it should get redirected somewhere else or should display some error message

But, when i download the same file using php or html code, it should get downloaded

for example when i use below code in a php file, it should get downloaded.

[a href="http://example.com/pdf/sample-pdf1.pdf" download]Download[/a]

Comment: Put the file outside your public folder, and fetch it from PHP when you want to actually download it.

Comment: hey @Qirel, i really don't understand, can u please explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Insert .htaccess file inside pdf directory with content:
"Deny from all" - 
That will not allow access that directory and files inside it via URL.

Comment: will that allow same files to be downloaded using a php script?

Comment: It restricts access but if you call the file from inside code, you should be able to download it.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: nope, it does not allow file to be downloaded from php script also